# Select ComboBox by value in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

How to select combo box by value in WinForms? I am setting combobox like that:

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.Text = "Test";
                item.Value = 1;

cmbComboBox.Items.Add(item);

internal class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I need to select where Value = 1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because [ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` only `IEnumerable` you can't use LINQ standard query operators.  However, just cheat a little bit by using `Cast<T>` to obtain a LINQ friendly queryable collection:

`var result = comboBox1.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().Where(i => (int.Parse(i.Value.ToString())) == 1);`

Comment: You have to cast `i.Value` to `(int)`, and then call `FirstOrDefault()` on the query which will return a ComboboxItem (or null).  Once you've got that you can determine its Index in the Items collection so you can set SelectedIndex().

Comment: True...I was assuming by "select" he meant make that ComboboxItem the selected one in the ComboBox.  I suppose you could also just set SelectedItem() to the returned value if that's the case.