# Assign Selected item for ComboBox that is filled with custom class

Tags: c#

So I have a ComboBox that is filled on formLoad by data within a database using a custom class.
Here is the class:

```
  public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

I fill the comboBox like so:

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ComboBoxItem itm = new ComboBoxItem();
            itm.Value = dr["Userid"];
            itm.Text = dr["UserName"].ToString();

            comboCoach.Items.Add(itm);

        }
```

For Example, if one of the ComboBox items that I add has the "object Value = 15".
And then I wanted to assign the comboBox.SelectedItem to the ComboBoxItem where the value = 15. How would I go about doing this?

I'm sure this is something simple that I have overlooked.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var matching = comboCoach.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(z => z.Value == 15);

if (matching != null)
    comboCoach.SelectedItem = matching;
```

Also see [Select ComboBox by value in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104646/select-combobox-by-value-in-winforms) .

Comment: Yes, this works as i needed it to. Thank you for your time :)